# How to use splitter in Existing route

Tags: apache-camel

I want to use splitter in existing route which is like

```
<route>

    < from uri : xyz>

    <process ref="xyz">

    <transform>
        <method ref="xyz" method="xyz"/>
    </transform>

    <split>
        <jsonpath>$</jsonpath>
    </split>

    <transform>
        <method ref="xyz" method="xyz"/>
    </transform>

    < to uri : xyz>
</route>
```

**(I want to use it like this so that I don't have to create multiple routes)**
But it is giving error that definition has no children on pipeline

It is working like this

```
<route>
    < from uri : xyz>
    <process ref="xyz">
    <transform>
        <method ref="xyz" method="xyz"/>
    </transform>
    < to uri : splitter>
</route>

<route>
< from uri : splitter>
<split>
    <jsonpath>$</jsonpath>
</split>
< to uri : transformer>
</route>

<route>
< from uri : transformer>
<transform>
    <method ref="xyz" method="xyz"/>
</transform>
< to uri : xyz>
</route>
```

By this I have to create 3 routes but I want to work in one single route and use splitter.
I am using camel version 3.20
Please suggest how can we achieve spliiter in single route.